# Salesforce1 App v 7.3.3 URL scheme links not working anymore

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile-url-scheme

I have an iOS app that uses REST api to display a list of Opportunities on a table view, when the user taps on a cell the app calls the URL that launches the Salesforce1 app with the right syntax so that the Opportunity is displayed on it.

This was working the last time I checked around a week ago but it isn't anymore when I checked today. It launches the Salesforce1 app but it does not redirect you to the Opportunity. The only thing that I noticed is that the app was updated to version 7.3.3 on the 4th of Jan 2016.

Knowing that there are 2 URL schemas that one can use I though one of them might have been deprecated but neither is working.

com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId=006580000022wNyAAI

salesforce1://sObject/006580000022wNyAAI/view

(I have also tried copying these links to a note in the Notes app and clicking on them, but I get the same behaviour, Salesforce1 app launches but the opportunity is not directly displayed).

Is anybody aware of any changes on the app in the latest version with regards to URL schemas?

Many thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 3):

You are right but this is not broken due to Salesforce1 app update. This is actually because **Apple has changed the way deep linking works in iOS 9.2 and above.**

Apple now uses Universal links for linking to other apps. Quoting the relevant text here

> Apple introduced Universal Links in iOS 9. These are deep links where,
>   instead of defining a custom URL scheme, you match a set of webpages
>   to locations in-app. When a user would open a webpage matched in this
>   way, iOS would automatically redirect into the app.

I verified that one of my existing apps which deep linked to SF1 does not work on my devices with iOS 9.2 There are links which suggest this is a known issue ([1](https://www.adjust.com/overview/features/2015/12/11/ios-9-2-deeplinking/) and [2](https://blog.branch.io/ios-9.2-redirection-update-uri-scheme-and-universal-links)) with other apps as well. I will double check it on my other app as well to be 100% sure though.